# Mac Java Path Issues with trying to run Android SDK

Tags: java, android, macos, sdk

I'm trying to run the android tool from command line and I keep getting

```
sdkmanager.jar not found
```

I've seen a few other questions with this, but none had a clear answer on how to fix it. I believe it's a path problem. It seems obviously a path problem. **But how do you change the path in Mac?**

I'm an experienced windows user and have always had to install java instead of it coming with the software updates. I even downloaded the 1.7jdk preview port they have for mac that's still in beta.

I just don't know how to change the path so it works. The other person who posted this issue added a **`EXPORT PATH=/somedir/android-sdk/:$PATH`** to her `.bash_profile` but there was no response as to whether it worked. I've tried it. It doesn't, and I wouldn't expect it to because there's no `sdkmanager.jar` anywhere in the android-sdk-macosx they give you.

Every tutorial on android I've found using Mac has come with ALOT more files than the current sdk you download from android does. I have two empty addon/platform directories and a tools directory with scripts in them. No jar files or anything else.

Please help!

Comment: Thanks for the help guys, but still not working.

ANY INFO or GUESSES at this point would be very appreciated.

All I did was create a .bash_profile and put

export JAVA_HOME=/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Home export PATH=/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Home:/Applications/android-sdk-macosx/platform-tools:$PATH

in it. And yes, I sourced it afterwards to make sure it went into effect. I tried tools/android from the command line. No go. Same message.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

today I fixed this :-) on Mac Lion (server):

1- open Terminal

2- Type ***cd ~*** to go to your home directory ( you will be there by default)

3- Type ***touch .profile*** to create a hidden file named profile

4- Type ***open -e .profile*** this will open the file you created in TextEdit

5- In the file, **type export PATH=${PATH}:FULL_PATH_WHERE_ANDROID_SDK/android-sdk-mac_86/platform-tools**

**FULL_PATH_WHERE_ANDROID_SDK**: where is sdk, don't forget / before, so it will be i.e.
***/users/mmm/sdk***

6- save file

7- exit TextEdit

8- quit Terminal, and Relaunch Terminal

9- Now type again : ***adb devices***  if you get

**>List of devices attached**

So you did it successfully ..

Good luck

Comment: Thank you so much dude...I can't wait to try it when I get home. Again Thanks!

Comment: Wait, I already see a problem...When you download the current version of the sdk android-sdk_r16-macosx.zip
from this location (pretty sure the legit one)
http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html

it has no platform-tools directory in it. The addon and platform directory are empty and only the tools dir has anything in it. You must be using an older version of the sdk?

Comment: Does anyone have an older version of the sdk they could provide a link for? Mine isn't matching up and frankly I think I used to be able to run it. I think I tried installing it way back before I had any interest in android dev and had no problems.

Answer (score 0):

It should be `Export PATH=/somedir/android-sdk/:$PATH`. This will append the android-sdk dir to the beginning of path. The example you posted is not exporting any variable.